# Folder permissions keep changing from www-data to root

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, permissions

A folder under the directory `/var/www/xml` keeps changing permission from `www-data` to`root`, meaning that no `php` file is able to write into the folder.

I think this happens when I restart the server.

`drwxr-xr-x 6 root www-data  4096 Sep 10 13:40 xml`

`drwxr-xr-x 6 www-data www-data  4096 Sep 10 13:40 xml`

How do I make sure this does not happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you the only person with root / sudo access to this server? If not, it is possible that someone else is changing the permissions and not notifying you.

Another thought would be a cron job that runs as the root user and issues a chown on that directory for whatever reason, e.g. such as after processing an xml feed file.

Comment: It seems to happen when I upload new files to the folder, I did the following so that all file permission in the folder are changed to www-data `chown www-data -R xml` but this makes no difference for newly uploaded files, is there a fix around this?

Comment: How are you uploading new files (e.g. wget, scp, ftp, etc) and as what user?

Comment: Im using SFTP  .

Comment: What user are you logging in as for your SFTP session? I'm guessing it is the root user, which is a very bad idea, but if so that would explain why the owner gets changed to the user that uploaded the file.

Comment: it is the root user

Comment: It is standard for uploaded files to take on the ownership of the user that uploaded the file. You will either have to manually change the owner after you upload the files or setup a cron job that changes the ownership.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem with `/var/run/lighttpd` set owned by `www-data` by something instead of `lighttpd` user. I added it to `www-data` group but apparently things still don't work sometimes, so I overrided the systemd service script with `systemctl edit lighttpd`:

```yaml
/etc/systemd/system/lighttpd.service.d/override.conf
-----------------------------------------
[Unit]
Description=Lighttpd Daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/log/lighttpd
ExecStartPre=/bin/chown lighttpd:lighttpd /var/log/lighttpd
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/lighttpd
ExecStartPre=/bin/chown lighttpd:lighttpd /var/run/lighttpd
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score -1):

Find out what changes the permission of the folder and fix it.

auditd can help.

Comment: He's asking **how**.